# Android GCM registration with Django csrf_exempt view. Best practices?

Tags: android, django, security, push-notification, csrf

During the Android GCM (push notification service) registration process, my **mobile client** has to make a **POST request** to a **Django view**. 
By default csrf_token is required for a view, however it could be **disabled** with a **@csrf_exempt decorator**.

My question is: what are the consequences of not having csrf check for the view? Would it make  sense if I compose a token from the mobile client (with some sort of salt)?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the nature of your view.

The csrf token is there to help prevent the invoking of an action you didnt intend to whilst already authenticated on the same PC. For example, a URL exists in your Django app http://www.example.com/person/delete/356 that would delete the person with the ID 356 when you POST to it. This might be ok normally as it requires authentication to fire it. However, what if you've logged into you Django application in one tab and someone sends you a phishing email (or similar) that contains the link "http://www.example.com/person/delete/356" - you click it and because you're already authenticated in another tab it works. By having Django expect a csrf token, Django is only going to action requests that it actually expects - i.e. Django knows its issued the token "12345ab" and therefore when a request with token "12345ab" is returned its fine to action, if its missing or you send "98765zx" it will fail. Read more about Django csrf tokens [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) and about Cross Site Request Forgery on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

If you have no authentication and the view doesn't action anything (i.e. it doesn't change data it just displays it) then the risk of making is @csrf_exempt is pretty low.

Likewise if this is occurring inside a mobile app and the view is authenticated then the authentication is not going to be shared amongst apps as it is with browser tabs so again, the risk is low.

You also have other options available, when setting up the HTTP request if you can somehow get the expected csrf token then you can set a header, much like you would during an AJAX call, read the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a number of factors, specifically what you're gathering besides the registration ID, and how the client is connecting to the server for the POST.

### Worst case scenario for GCM registration without CSRF verification

An attacker could register a device under his own control to the victim's account, and receive notifications meant for the victim.

Depending on what you're doing, this might not be that terrible, especially considering that
the GCM messages aren't supposed to contain any sensitive information anyways, and just act as a trigger to loading information under more secure methods.

(i.e. if the GCM triggers an activity that loads up a new page in the client device that's based off authentication, since the attacker's app won't be authenticated using the victim's credentials, they can't see sensitive information).

It'd more be a nuisance than anything else.

### If you want to protect against this

1. Set a token as Nam mentioned -- if you initiate the GCM registration activity from the server (i.e. from a JavaScript callback), just set a token that the client needs to pass back with the registration. A CSRF request will be asynchronous to this step, and will fail due to lack of token.
2. If your app communicates with the server via a sub-domain exclusive to the app, (i.e. app.site.com with auth cookies at the sub-domain level), as long as the application exclusively loads your own domain (i.e. no external websites), and the server only allows access to the registration view on that subdomain, it'd be extremely hard to exploit. CSRF attacks will likely happen in the browser.
3. Pull the CSRF exempt value from the site cookie within the app using the CookieManager, and add that as a POST variable with the request. Then you don't need to make the view CSRF exempt. This is essentially how Django handles AJAX CSRF. Be sure to use the `@ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator prior to registering to ensure the CSRF cookie is set in the client.

### Conclusion

Honestly though, CSRF for GCM registration is extremely low on the "issues to keep you up at night" totem pole. CSRF is more an issue in account management (such as changing passwords, making bank transactions, etc).